# How to add attributes in array to XML conversion in PHP

Tags: php, xml

i am converting an array into XML data in PHP

```
        $test_array = array (
            'bla' => 'param',
            'foo' => 'param',

        );
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<params/>');
        array_walk_recursive($test_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
        dd($xml->asXML());
```

the XML i got looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<params>
<param>bla</param>
<param>foo</param>
</params>
```

i want to add attributes in the xml items like this :

```
<param name='paramname' type='int'>bla</param>
```

how to modify my array in order to add atributes into XML items ?

Comment: It may be worth spending some time learning how to use SimpleXML a bit more, there is a lot you can do but not all of it is as simple as run a one liner against an array.

Comment: and which function could help me in that ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**set key:**

```
$xml->foo['bar']= 'baz';
```

**addAttribute:**

```
$xml->addAttribute('key','value');
```

You can use this in the loop or in other ways ...

This is just a way to add a parameter

**Example:**

```
$test_array = array(
    'bla' => 'param',
    'foo' => 'param',
);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<params/>');
foreach ($test_array as $key => $value) {
    $child = $xml->addChild($value, $key);
    $child->addAttribute('key','value');
}
print_r($xml->asXML());
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<params>
    <param key="value">bla</param>
    <param key="value">foo</param>
</params>
```

**Be sure to read the link below before using SimpleXMLElement:**
https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: this added only one row ? how to add parameters in every row

Comment: You can use this in the loop or in other ways ...
This is just a way to add a parameter